# What numbers can you pass as verbosity in running Python Unit Test Suites?

Tags: python, unit-testing, verbosity

The Python unittest framework has a concept of verbosity that I can't seem to find defined anywhere. For instance, I'm running test cases like this ([like in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example)):

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyAwesomeTest)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The only number I've ever seen passed as verbosity is 2. What is this magic number, what does it mean, what what else can I pass?

Comment: When you looked at the source, what did you find?

Comment: @S.Lott When you used the Force, why weren't you kind?

Comment: Also `unittest.main(verbosity=2)`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You only have 3 different levels:

- 0 ***(quiet)***: you just get the total numbers of tests executed and the global result
- 1 ***(default)***: you get the same plus a dot for every successful test or a F for every failure
- 2 ***(verbose)***: you get the help string of every test and the result

You can use command line args rather than the verbosity argument: `--quiet` and `--verbose` which would do something similar to passing 0 or 2 to the runner.

Comment: You can also pass `python3 -m unittest testfile.py -vvv` for verbosity=3