# How to get the result of an individual test case?

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

Is there a way of getting the result of an individual test case? I want to log the name of each test case and if it passed or not. I do not want to spend time writing into the log for every single test case, so I would like something like that in tearDown.

Comment: You might be able to get that info just by enabling verbose output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322575/what-numbers-can-you-pass-as-verbosity-in-running-python-unit-test-suites

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer.

Comment: Actually wait.. they are just displayed as a text.. how do I get an array of the results per each test? I could dig through the implementation, but it's quite cumbersome.